# Using Chef to Manage a File With Instance-Specific Contents?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm using a Chef recipe to manage some Tomcat servers running on Amazon EC2 instances. It works great for me in scenarios where I need lots of identical Tomcats in use all having the same .jars/Java options/etc.

However, I've hit a use case that I'm not sure how to handle. Basically, every Tomcat has a context.xml (located at /etc/tomcat7) file that I'd like to configure to have a Manager element that needs to point to a particular endpoint (an Elasticache in Amazon corresponding to its name, so TomcatA has ElasticacheA and so on). Initially, I had the following code in my recipe with the associated context.xml template:

```
elasticache="TomcatA"
elasticache_suffix = ".xxx.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com"

template 'tomcat context.xml configuration' do
 path ::File.join(tomcat_directory, 'context.xml')
 source 'context.xml.erb'
 variables(
{
            :elasticache => elasticache,
            :elasticache_suffix => elasticache_suffix
}
          )
 owner 'root'
 group node["tomcat"]["group"]
 mode 00644
 notifies :restart, 'service[tomcat7]', :delayed
 end
```

Template for context.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version   2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or    implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
 -->
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application ->
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Manager
className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
memcachedNodes="<%=@elasticache%><%=@elasticache_suffix%>:11211"
requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
sessionBackupAsync="true"
sticky="true"
copyCollectionsForSerialization="false"
/>

<!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
     on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
-->

</Context>
```

However, this clearly doesn't work for my purposes since Chef will ensure that ALL existing setups are using ElasticacheA.

I can use the AWS CLI to get the Elasticache name value I need, but how do I make sure Chef won't overwrite existing setups with the value each time? Ideally, each run of the recipe would produce a new result for this template that wouldn't affect any setups already in use.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options here. All comes to node attributes, instead of hardcoded `elasticache` variable, you should use node attribute, for example `node["tomcat"]["elasticache"]`. You can adjust it to each deployment in two ways.

1. Create [environment](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html) for each type of Tomcat deployment, assign different environment to different deployment types and overwrite attribute there.
2. Create 'wrapper' cookbook/recipe, which will set/override node attribute and include your basic recipe which does Tomcat setup.